# django datepicker on datatable

Tags: javascript, django, datepicker

I have to apply datepicker to my datatable to filter the data between two date range. I have applied my things and tried different codes but nothing worked out. My table contains date in the format( example- July 16,2019). I know it can be done by javascript but I am unable to do so. Please help.

```
 <table id="table table-mutasi" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-key-events="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-resizable="true" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="saveId" data-show-export="true" data-click-to-select="true">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                                    <th data-field="id">center</th>
                                    <th data-field="cabin" >cabin</th>
                                    <th data-field="boooked_date">Booked date</th>
                                    <th data-field="release_date">Release Date</th>
                                    <th data-field="client">Client</th>
                                    <th data-field="booked_by">Booked by</th>
                                    {% if not request.user.is_superuser %}
                                     <th>Actions</th>
                                    {% endif %}

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                 {% for object in object_list %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ object.premises}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ object.cabin }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ object.booked_date }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ object.release_date }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ object.client }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ object.booked_by }}</td>
                                    {% if not request.user.is_superuser %}
                                    <td>
                                          <a href="{% url 'manager:BookingUpdate' pk=object.id %}" style="color:black; margin-left:8px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                                          <input type="hidden" id="cendel"  value="{{object.id }}">

                                          <a href="#" style="color:black ;margin_left:8px;" id="delete"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>                                         </td>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </tr>
                                 {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: why not format the date with `|date:" ... "` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Comment: Can you help me with javascript code too. I'm new to it and I have tried many codes but nothing worked for me. @HenryM